# I want arrow icon in my drop down child items and change the background colour of my tabs

Tags: html, css

[image: this is the problem]
Please tell me the simple method
I want to add pause/play icon in all my parent child of drop down menu.
Also how can I change my tabs background colour?

```css
#nav {
     float: left;
    font: 14px calibri, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
     border: 1px solid #121314;
     border-top: 1px solid #2b2e30;
     -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
     -moz-border-radius: 5px;
     border-radius: 5px;
     overflow:visible;
  line-height:7px;
}

#nav ul {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 list-style:none;
}

#nav ul li {
 float:left;
}

#nav ul li a {
    float: left;
 color:#d4d4d4;
     padding: 8px 20px;  /* change the height of whole menu*/
 text-decoration:none;
     background:#3C4042;
  background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(59,63,65)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(72,76,77)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(75,77,77)) );
 background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(59,63,65) 9%, rgb(72,76,77) 55%, rgb(75,77,77) 78% );
 background: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(59,63,65) 9%, rgb(72,76,77) 55%, rgb(75,77,77) 78% );
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset, 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
 border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
        border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 
}

#nav ul li a:hover,
#nav ul li:hover > a {
     color:#FFF;   /* change tabs font hover color */
     background:#3C4042;
 background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(77,79,79)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(67,70,71)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(69,70,71)) );
 background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77,79,79) 9%, rgb(67,70,71) 55%, rgb(69,70,71) 78% );
 background: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77,79,79) 9%, rgb(67,70,71) 55%, rgb(69,70,71) 78% );
     text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 -1px #000;

}

#nav li ul a:hover, 
#nav ul li li:hover > a  {
    color:#FFF;        /*  change the drop down font color*/
   background: #5C9ACD;
 background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.17, rgb(61,111,177)), color-stop(0.51, rgb(80,136,199)), color-stop(1, rgb(92,154,205)) );
 background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(61,111,177) 17%, rgb(80,136,199) 51%, rgb(92,154,205) 100% );
 background: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(61,111,177) 17%, rgb(80,136,199) 51%, rgb(92,154,205) 100% );
     border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
     border-top: 1px solid #7BAED9;
     text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}



#nav li ul {
 overflow:visible;
     background:#3C4042;
     background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(77,79,79)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(67,70,71)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(69,70,71)) );
     background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77,79,79) 9%, rgb(67,70,71) 55%, rgb(69,70,71) 78% );
     background-image: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77,79,79) 9%, rgb(67,70,71) 55%, rgb(69,70,71) 78% );
     border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
     left: -999em;
     margin: 32px 0 0;        /* change the position of drop down menu, up and down.*/
     position: absolute;
     width: 160px;
     z-index: 9999;
     box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset; 
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset; 
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset; 
     border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#nav li:hover ul {
     left: auto;
}

#nav li ul a {
     background: none;
     border: 0 none;
     margin-right: 0;
     width: 120px;
     box-shadow: none;
     -moz-box-shadow: none;
     -webkit-box-shadow: none;
     border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
     border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}

#nav li li ul {
     margin: -1px 0 0 160px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 0 10px 10px 10px;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 10px 10px 10px;
     border-radius: 0 10px 10px 10px;
     visibility:hidden;
}

#nav li li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
}
#nav li:hover > ul {
    left: auto;
}





#nav ul ul li:last-child > a {
 -moz-border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
 border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
}

#nav ul ul ul li:first-child > a {
 -moz-border-radius:0 10px 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius:0 10px 0 0;
 border-radius:0 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>

<li><a href="#">Our Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="#">One Dropdown</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Level 2.1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Level 2.2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Level 2.3</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Level 2.4</a></li>

 <li><a href="#">Level 2.5</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Three Levels</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Level 2.1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Level 2.2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Level 2.3 ></a>

  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Level 2.3.1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Level 2.3.2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Level 2.3.3 ></a>


<ul>
<li><a href='URL LINK TO LABEL/WEBSITE/PAGE'>SUB-CATEGORY 2A</a></li>
<li><a href='URL LINK TO LABEL/WEBSITE/PAGE'>SUB-CATEGORY 2B</a></li>
</ul>






</li>
  <li><a href="#">Level 2.3.4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Level 2.3.5</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Level 2.3.6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Level 2.3.7</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">Level 2.4</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Level 2.5</a></li>
 </ul>

</li>
<li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
<li><a href="#">AlhamduLillah</a></li>


</ul>








</div>
```

Comment: bro want this icon in drop down list

Comment: Yeah bro problem is almost solve

Comment: but one more thing i want this icon at the end of the line

Comment: Bro you are absolitely right but please tell me this one thing please

Comment: &nbsp; is a code that tells html *this is a space* since html needs to reckonize spaces and tabs as code language. &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; equals to one *tab*. Hope this helps you!

Comment: Oh thank u very very much my dear

Comment: May you live long and happy

Comment: yes i already done bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm Okey as long Patrick Mlr do the answer i just improve it by little bit hope it will help 
As long its dropdown you need down arrow and, left arrow when mouseenter, hovering look this also this will change background color as you want 
Jquery way 
and fixed margin

Edited

&#9660 ; is ▼

&#9658 ; is ►

JQuery has mouse events this is one of them Mouseenter, Mouseleave you can read [Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) in here

this is simpler than you see this will check hovering over your tabs if your tab has class named hoverdrop, it will find i in that hovered tab, after that this adding ▼ in found **i** also changing background

IF ANYTHING YOU CANT UNDERSTAND MENTION AND ASK I WILL TRY TO HELP AS POSSIBLE

```js
$('#nav ul li').mouseenter(function() {
if($(this).hasClass('hoverdrop')){
  $(this).find('i').html('&#9660;');
}
}).mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).find('i').html('&#9658;');
});

$('#nav ul li a').mouseenter(function() {
$(this).css('color','#fff').css('background-color','#5f5f5f');
}).mouseleave(function() {
$(this).css('color','#d4d4d4').css('background-color','#3C4042');
});
```

```css
#nav {
  float: left;
  font: 14px calibri, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid #121314;
  border-top: 1px solid #2b2e30;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: visible;
  line-height: 7px;
}

#nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#nav ul li {
  float: left;
}

#nav ul li a {
  float: left;
  color: #d4d4d4;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  /* change the height of whole menu*/
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #3C4042;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

#nav ul li a:hover,
#nav ul li:hover > a {
  
}

#nav li ul a:hover,
#nav ul li li:hover > a {

}

#nav li ul {
  overflow: visible;
  background: #3C4042;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(77, 79, 79)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(67, 70, 71)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(69, 70, 71)));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77, 79, 79) 9%, rgb(67, 70, 71) 55%, rgb(69, 70, 71) 78%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77, 79, 79) 9%, rgb(67, 70, 71) 55%, rgb(69, 70, 71) 78%);
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  left: -999em;
  margin: 22px 0 0;
  /* change the position of drop down menu, up and down.*/
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px;
  z-index: 9999;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#nav li:hover ul {
  left: auto;
}

#nav li ul a {
  background: none;
  border: 0 none;
  margin-right: 0;
  width: 120px;
  box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}

#nav li li ul {
  margin: -1px 0 0 160px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#nav li li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
}

#nav li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
}

#nav ul ul li:last-child > a {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

#nav ul ul ul li:first-child > a {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Our Portfolio</a></li>
    <li class='hoverdrop'><a href="#">One Dropdown <i class='arrows'>&#9658;</i></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2.3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2.4</a></li>

        <li><a href="#">Level 2.5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='hoverdrop'><a href="#">Three Levels<i class='arrows'>&#9658;</i></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2.2</a></li>
        <li class='hoverdrop'><a href="#">Level 2.3<i class='arrows'>&#9658;</i></a>

          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Level 2.3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Level 2.3.2</a></li>
            <li class='hoverdrop'><a href="#">Level 2.3.3 <i class='arrows'>&#9658;</i></a>


              <ul>
                <li><a href='URL LINK TO LABEL/WEBSITE/PAGE'>SUB-CATEGORY 2A</a></li>
                <li><a href='URL LINK TO LABEL/WEBSITE/PAGE'>SUB-CATEGORY 2B</a></li>
              </ul>






            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Level 2.3.4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Level 2.3.5</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Level 2.3.6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Level 2.3.7</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2.4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2.5</a></li>
      </ul>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">AlhamduLillah</a></li>


  </ul>








</div>
```

Comment: Well.. It changes the color "permanently" and it changes the arrow from "one dropdown" if you hover on any other link.. It this really what you're looking for?

Comment: This is not the correct answer and thereby should not be marked as the correct answer. This will mislead the community if any other people in the near future will find this post.

Comment: @Tomm but i just try to do what he said **how can I change my tabs background color?** and this is 1 way to change background color when hovering. If he needs back to default color when mouseleave. tbh this is what he said in question

Comment: 1 You used the wrong unicode. 2 You did not tell him how to add spaces between strings. 3 You did not explain a single thing you did. 4 You still think this is a good answer? even though i helped him out with everything? and i explained my help in the answer section which is the correct answer with right explanation for people in the near future comming to this thread.....

Comment: @Tomm oh here is your fish, teach a guy how catch a fish not give a fish **Moral** i prefer. I just hoping he will dig it up from what i coded but you just prefer just give a fish in bucket to catch so i edited what it his goal. You know what i am trying to say

Comment: @Tomm i copy your answer don't joke. Yeah your answer `<li><a href="#">Level 2.3.3 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &#9658;</a>` is best asnwer

Comment: Its the explanation on my answer that is making it the best answer, ps also look at the comment section from his post i am actually the only person *really* helping him

Comment: Yeah delete your comments

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it like this?

I just added `&#9658;` to the dropdowns and fixed the margin of `#nav li ul` to `23px`. *Maybe this was just a snippet problem. If yes, don't mind the change then.*

```css
#nav {
     float: left;
    font: 14px calibri, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
     border: 1px solid #121314;
     border-top: 1px solid #2b2e30;
     -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
     -moz-border-radius: 5px;
     border-radius: 5px;
     overflow:visible;
  line-height:7px;
}

#nav ul {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 list-style:none;
}

#nav ul li {
 float:left;
}

#nav ul li a {
    float: left;
 color:#d4d4d4;
     padding: 8px 20px;  /* change the height of whole menu*/
 text-decoration:none;
     background:#3C4042;
  background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(59,63,65)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(72,76,77)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(75,77,77)) );
 background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(59,63,65) 9%, rgb(72,76,77) 55%, rgb(75,77,77) 78% );
 background: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(59,63,65) 9%, rgb(72,76,77) 55%, rgb(75,77,77) 78% );
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset, 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
 border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
        border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 
}

#nav ul li a:hover,
#nav ul li:hover > a {
     color:#FFF;   /* change tabs font hover color */
     background:#3C4042;
 background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(77,79,79)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(67,70,71)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(69,70,71)) );
 background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77,79,79) 9%, rgb(67,70,71) 55%, rgb(69,70,71) 78% );
 background: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77,79,79) 9%, rgb(67,70,71) 55%, rgb(69,70,71) 78% );
     text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 -1px #000;

}

#nav li ul a:hover, 
#nav ul li li:hover > a  {
    color:#FFF;        /*  change the drop down font color*/
   background: #5C9ACD;
 background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.17, rgb(61,111,177)), color-stop(0.51, rgb(80,136,199)), color-stop(1, rgb(92,154,205)) );
 background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(61,111,177) 17%, rgb(80,136,199) 51%, rgb(92,154,205) 100% );
 background: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(61,111,177) 17%, rgb(80,136,199) 51%, rgb(92,154,205) 100% );
     border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
     border-top: 1px solid #7BAED9;
     text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}



#nav li ul {
 overflow:visible;
     background:#3C4042;
     background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(77,79,79)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(67,70,71)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(69,70,71)) );
     background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77,79,79) 9%, rgb(67,70,71) 55%, rgb(69,70,71) 78% );
     background-image: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77,79,79) 9%, rgb(67,70,71) 55%, rgb(69,70,71) 78% );
     border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
     left: -999em;
     margin: 23px 0 0;        /* change the position of drop down menu, up and down.*/
     position: absolute;
     width: 160px;
     z-index: 9999;
     box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset; 
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset; 
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset; 
     border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#nav li:hover ul {
     left: auto;
}

#nav li ul a {
     background: none;
     border: 0 none;
     margin-right: 0;
     width: 120px;
     box-shadow: none;
     -moz-box-shadow: none;
     -webkit-box-shadow: none;
     border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
     border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}

#nav li li ul {
     margin: -1px 0 0 160px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 0 10px 10px 10px;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 10px 10px 10px;
     border-radius: 0 10px 10px 10px;
     visibility:hidden;
}

#nav li li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
}
#nav li:hover > ul {
    left: auto;
}





#nav ul ul li:last-child > a {
 -moz-border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
 border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
}

#nav ul ul ul li:first-child > a {
 -moz-border-radius:0 10px 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius:0 10px 0 0;
 border-radius:0 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>

<li><a href="#">Our Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="#">One Dropdown &#9658;</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Level 2.1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Level 2.2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Level 2.3</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Level 2.4</a></li>

 <li><a href="#">Level 2.5</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Three Levels &#9658;</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Level 2.1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Level 2.2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Level 2.3 &#9658;</a>

  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Level 2.3.1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Level 2.3.2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Level 2.3.3 &#9658;</a>


<ul>
<li><a href='URL LINK TO LABEL/WEBSITE/PAGE'>SUB-CATEGORY 2A</a></li>
<li><a href='URL LINK TO LABEL/WEBSITE/PAGE'>SUB-CATEGORY 2B</a></li>
</ul>






</li>
  <li><a href="#">Level 2.3.4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Level 2.3.5</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Level 2.3.6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Level 2.3.7</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">Level 2.4</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Level 2.5</a></li>
 </ul>

</li>
<li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
<li><a href="#">AlhamduLillah</a></li>


</ul>








</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Answer to your question

```
&#9658;
```

is the uni code for the ► symbol

Adding

```
&nbsp;
```

To your line will function as a space since html doesnt reckonize spaces and tabs on its own.

Your line of code would look something like this

```
<li><a href="#">Level 2.3.3 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &#9658;</a>
```

Hope this helps you and or others out.